# Syntax error near "ORDER BY order DESC" in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, mysql-error-1064

Why, when I try to do an order by query, do I always get an error telling me to check the syntax by the ORDER BY 'order' DESC?

Here's my query:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY order DESC;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`order` is a reserved word in SQL; case does not matter. It *must* be quoted when [used as an identifier](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html). From the [MySQL Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) documentation:

> Certain words such as SELECT, DELETE, or BIGINT [or ORDER] are reserved and require special treatment for use as identifiers such as table and column names.

Traditional MySQL quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY `order` DESC;
```

[Proper (ANSI) SQL quotes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) (some databases support `[order]` as well):

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY "order" DESC;
```

Although I would consider renaming the column to avoid such confusing issues in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Order is a reserved keyword.

Try,

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY `order` DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

The column name is `order` which is a keyword.  You need to do this:

```
SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY `order` DESC;
```